# What is the justification for the theoretical value of the adiabatic index of $\rm CO_2$ of 1.30 at room temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, gas

I'm currently investigating an experiment to determine the adiabatic index of helium, nitrogen and carbon dioxide at room temperature and am attempting to come up with / justify theoretical values of their adiabatic indices / ratios of their heat capacities. Nitrogen and helium are easy, but for carbon dioxide, I am attempting to take account of some vibrational degrees of freedom. To do so, I have looked into vibrational partition functions, but I can't really make sense of how to extract additional degrees of freedom from the partition function. Any help in justifying where 1.30 comes from would be much appreciated,

Comment: It is not theory, the literature value comes from experiment.

Comment: @Pieter Good point in your comment to my answer, that I overlooked. I have deleted it.

Comment: @Pieter But is there a way of justifying where it comes from? From the vibrational partition function I have it that there is approximately a 20% chance that the CO2 molecule is vibrating in one of its given modes. Is this sufficient to say that it has an additional 2 degrees of freedom? This would take the theoretical value of gamma to 9/7 or approx. 1.29

Comment: There are the symmetric and asymmetric stretch modes that should be frozen at room temperature. Then there are the two bending modes. Their vibrational quantum is 82 meV.  That is three times as large as $kT$ at room temperature, so equipartition would not be valid.

Comment: What alternative approach would be sensible then? Statistical mechanics dictates that although it's not guaranteed that they will be vibrating, there is still a probability of it - what applies in the place of equipartition in this case?

Comment: One could do the numerical calculation of $c_v(T)$, just like for Einstein resonators in solids, when $c_v$ is smaller than the Dulong & Petit value.